# How to use GetRepliesRequest call in Telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon, telegram-api

There is api method [messages.getReplies](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getReplies) in Telegram API and the equivalent of the same is
[functions.messages.GetRepliesRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_replies.html) in the Telethon.
But this method is not returning the expected replies/comments to the post. Instead, it returns multiple messages including the replies to the requested message_id and other messages also which are not even the replies to the requested message_id.

```py
for conv in client.iter_messages(channel.id):
    if conv.reply_to:
       # get parent message this message reply to
       original_message = conv.get_reply_message()  
       try:
           #iterate all the replies for the parent message
           for reply in client.iter_messages(channel.id,
                                          reply_to=original_message.id):
               print('\tReply message  -> ', reply.to_dict())
       except telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MsgIdInvalidError:
             print('exception ***************')
```

Here it returns the replies to the input message.id in the argument `reply_to` including the messages which are not the replies to the input message.id.

(I checked the response from of the method call(inner for loop) and their `reply_to_msg_id` differs from what i requested to get the result).

I could not understand the behaviour of these replies getting in the result.

Also Telegram API docs are not good in shape with example and explantion.

- What and how messages are considered as `reply` to the message in the telegram?
- How telegram decides upon the messages whether it is a reply or a normal message?
- if a message is reply, then to which message this is a reply?

Answer (score 1):

Given a broadcast channel with comments enabled (let's say the channel's username is `username`), and a post with a discussion started (comments) for the channel post with message ID 1001, the following code will print all comments for post 1001 in channel `username`:

```py
async for m in client.iter_messages('username', reply_to=1001):
    print(m.text)
```

This is equivalent to clicking on the "# comment(s)" button in Telegram Desktop. Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce what you mention here:

> But this method is not returning the expected replies/comments to the post. Instead, it returns multiple messages including the replies to the requested message_id and other messages also which are not even the replies to the requested message_id.

Now, for the other questions:

> What and how messages are considered as reply to the message in the telegram?

Let's look at the problem from a different angle: `send_message` with `comment_to`.

First, `messages.getDiscussionMessage` must be used on the source broadcast channel with the source message ID. This will return the corresponding "discussion message" in the linked "discussion megagroup channel".

Now, `messages.sendMessage` can be used to send a message in the linked discussion megagroup channel to **reply to** the corresponding discussion message.

As you can see, "comments" are simply "replies to" the corresponding message of the discussion group. Hence the name, `reply_to`, during `iter_messages`.

> How telegram decides upon the messages whether it is a reply or a normal message?

In a given chat, messages can reply to other previous messages in the same chat (in Telethon, `message.reply_to`). However, for channel comments, they're also replies in a way (just in a different chat), hence the parameter name. I tried to stick with Telegram's naming convention and solve the confusion by documenting the parameter but that might've been the wrong choice.

> if a message is reply, then to which message this is a reply?

This can be found through `message.reply_to`.